# Dividing array into chunks of almost equal sum

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

The code for dividing the chunks is provided by this code snippet:

```
def chunks(lst, n):     #n here is 4
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]
```

As an input I have a list with the following integers:

```
[11, 45, 74, 24, 27, 55, 37, 97, 15, 36, 54, 7, 41, 77, 28, 36, 22, 214, 110, 40, 41, 14, 6, 35, 6, 7, 62, 2, 34, 1, 30, 5, 4, 8, 9, 7, 5, 7, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2]
```

I want to generate 4 chunks with that. As an output i get the following:

```
[[11, 45, 74, 24, 27, 55, 37, 97, 15, 36, 54, 7], 
[41, 77, 28, 36, 22, 214, 110, 40, 41, 14, 6, 35], 
[6, 7, 62, 2, 34, 1, 30, 5, 4, 8, 9, 7], 
[5, 7, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2]]
```

My problem is that the second list in the output has a higher weight than the other ones; the distribution of the numbers is not quite fair.
Can anyone give me an idea how to get a fair distribution of the numbers in the chunks by including the integers?

I've done an example by hand:

Input: `[11,20,2,4,8,13,16,0,1,0,3,6]`

Output: `[[20,1,0,0],[16,6],[13,8],[11,4,3,2]]`

Comment: Do you have a measure on how "even" you want the distribution to be ? A solution would be to sort your input list, and then pick 1 out of n elements for each chunk

Comment: Here an example with less integers: [11,20,2,4,8,13,16,0,1,0,3,6] 
wanted output: [[20,1],[16,6],[13,8],[11,4,3,2]]
I made this by hand and i dont know how to code it

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the minimal reproducible example ?

Comment: hey @menbar i didn't undestand your question man.  your example seems a little wrong at first ... [16,3,2 should be a chunk ,, and [11,6,4] should be another right?

Comment: Yes, in the output are 4 chunks. every chunk is given in a list

Comment: How is this related to multiprocessing?

Comment: This chunks are send to a process which parse my data. The numbers are part of the list, which is cruicial

Comment: Ok. so you already know the multiprocess thing right? If yes, then I suggest you can remove the multiprocess tag from the question to remove the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can first try to divide an array into 2 parts such that their sum is almost equal.
Then once we have the 2 sets, we can further apply the same process on each of them to get 2*2 = 4 sets of equal sum.

The algorithm to divide an array into 2 parts of approximately equal sum is as follows:

- Initialize 2 empty sets to hold our answer.
- Sort the array in reverse order.
- While maintaining the sum of the 2 sets, iterate over all the elements from array and append them into the set which has the lesser sum.
- Note that this is just an approximate algorithm. If we want to find the exactly optimal answer, then we can model this problem as the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), and find if we can divide the array into 2 parts, where one of the set has the sum `sum/2` or `sum/2 - 1` or `sum/2 - 2` ... `0` (trying each of them in that order). This is significantly slower compared to our approximate solution.

```
def divide_almost_equally_into_2(arr):
    set1 = []
    set2 = []
    sum1 = sum2 = arr_idx = 0
    while arr_idx < len(arr):
        if sum1 < sum2:
            set1.append(arr[arr_idx])
            sum1 += arr[arr_idx]
        else:
            set2.append(arr[arr_idx])
            sum2 += arr[arr_idx]
        arr_idx += 1
    return set1, set2


def divide_almost_equally_into_4(arr):
    arr.sort(reverse=True)
    set1, set2 = divide_almost_equally_into_2(arr)
    set11, set12 = divide_almost_equally_into_2(set1)
    set21, set22 = divide_almost_equally_into_2(set2)
    return [set11, set12, set21, set22]


def main():
    arr = [11,20,2,4,8,13,16,0,1,0,3,6]
    set1, set2, set3, set4 = divide_almost_equally_into_4(arr)
    print(f"{arr}   {sum(arr)}\n")
    print(f"{set1}   {sum(set1)}")
    print(f"{set2}   {sum(set2)}")
    print(f"{set3}   {sum(set3)}")
    print(f"{set4}   {sum(set4)}")


main()
```

Output:

```
[20, 16, 13, 11, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]   84

[13, 8]   21
[16, 3, 2]   21
[11, 6, 4]   21
[20, 1, 0, 0]   21
```

EDIT:

To generalize the same algorithm to 'n' number of splits, we can use a heap:

- Create a min-heap of size 'n', where each element is a tuple of the form (current_sum_of_set_i, i).
- So, initially heap will contain elements `(0, 0), (0, 1) ... (0, n-1)`.
- Now iterate over the reverse-sorted array, and assign each element to the set present at the top of the heap.
- Update the heap element of the set with the new sum of the element added to it.

```py
import heapq


def divide_almost_equally(arr, num_chunks):
    arr = sorted(arr, reverse=True)
    heap = [(0, idx) for idx in range(num_chunks)]
    heapq.heapify(heap)
    sets = {}
    for i in range(num_chunks):
        sets[i] = []
    arr_idx = 0
    while arr_idx < len(arr):
        set_sum, set_idx = heapq.heappop(heap)
        sets[set_idx].append(arr[arr_idx])
        set_sum += arr[arr_idx]
        heapq.heappush(heap, (set_sum, set_idx))
        arr_idx += 1
    return sets.values()


def main():
    arr = [11,20,2,4,8,13,16,0,1,0,3,6]
    set1, set2, set3, set4 = divide_almost_equally(arr, 4)
    print(f"{sorted(arr, reverse=True)}   {sum(arr)}\n")
    print(f"{set1}   {sum(set1)}")
    print(f"{set2}   {sum(set2)}")
    print(f"{set3}   {sum(set3)}")
    print(f"{set4}   {sum(set4)}")


main()
```

Output:

```
[20, 16, 13, 11, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]   84

[20, 1]   21
[16, 4, 0, 0]   20
[13, 6, 3]   22
[11, 8, 2]   21
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there even a way, where i can say, how many chunks i want? In the example i said i need 4 chunks. What about, when i need 6? is there an easy way to form your code? Many thanks!

Comment: Updated it with a more general solution. Had fun while thinking about it :)

Comment: Could you help me generating chunks with this kind of input? [[11,"a"], [20,"a"], [2,"a"], [4,"a"], [8,"a"], [13,"a"], [16,"a"], [0,"a"], [1,"a"],[0,"a"], [3,"a"],[6,"a"] ] 
The chunks should be generated with the integers but the strings in the list must follow the integer? Many thanks!

Comment: is there any way to get result without changing order(here you used sorting), Many thanks

Comment: @AkshayBandivadekar I have a solution that respects the array order

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution where the sum of each chunk is less than or equal to a threshold. This solution is inspired by the algorithm proposed by Anmol Singh Jaggi.

In the function below, the input set is divided recursively till the summation of each chunk is less than or equal to the Threshold

The number of the chunk is increasing linearly, but you could change according to your preference, such as `num_chunks = num_chunks*2`

```
def divide_almost_equally(arr, num_chunks,Threshold):
    divideMore = 0
    arr = sorted(arr, reverse=True)
    set_sum = np.zeros(num_chunks)
    sets = {}
    for i in range(num_chunks):
        sets[i] = []
    arr_idx = 0
    while arr_idx < len(arr):
        ChunkIndx = np.argmin(set_sum)
        sets[ChunkIndx].append(arr[arr_idx])
        set_sum[ChunkIndx] = set_sum[ChunkIndx] + arr[arr_idx]
        arr_idx = arr_idx + 1
    for total in set_sum:
        if(total>Threshold):
            divideMore = 1
            break
    if(divideMore == 1):
      num_chunks = num_chunks + 1
      return divide_almost_equally(arr, num_chunks,Threshold)
    else:
        return sets, num_chunks

if __name__ == "__main__":
   input = np.arange(0,100)
   Set, num_chunks = divide_almost_equally(np.arange(0,100), 1,100) # start with num_chunks = 1num_chunks = 1
   for chunk_indx in range(num_chunks): 
      print(Set[chunk_indx],'-- >',np.sum(Set[chunk_indx]))
```

Comment: This method does not respect the order of the values

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general solution that splits the array into chunks of almost equal sum, while **respecting the array order**.

```py
import math
from typing import Annotated, List


def split_equal_sum(arr: List[int], num_chunks: int) -> List[List[int]]:
    if num_chunks > len(arr):
        raise ValueError(
            f"Cannot split array of length {len(arr)} into {num_chunks} chunks."
        )

    def _split_in_two(
        arr: List[int], sleft: int = 1, sright: int = 1
    ) -> Annotated[List[int], 2]:
        left, right = arr[:sleft], arr[-sright:]
        for i in range(sleft + sright, len(arr)):
            if (sum(left) * sright) >= (sum(right) * sleft):
                right = arr[-len(right) - 1 :]
            else:
                left = arr[: len(left) + 1]
        return [left, right]

    if num_chunks > 1:
        sleft, sright = math.floor(num_chunks / 2), math.ceil(num_chunks / 2)
        left, right = _split_in_two(arr, sleft, sright)
        return split_equal_sum(left, sleft) + split_equal_sum(right, sright)
    return [arr]
```

the `_split_in_two` is a helper method that splits the array into two chunks of equal sum that allows for the relative chunk weight. So if we would split an array into three chunks `A, B, C`, we can do this in two steps:

```py
AB, C = _split_in_two(values, 2, 1) # AB is twice the sum of C
A, B = _split_in_two(AB, 1, 1)
```

and `split_equal_sum` keeps on splitting the array until all `num_chunks` are equal to 1:

```py
>>> split_equal_sum([11, 20, 2, 4, 8, 13, 16, 0, 1, 0, 3, 6], 4)
[[11, 20], [2, 4, 8], [13], [16, 0, 1, 0, 3, 6]]
```

- took into account odd distribution, so for example `split_equal_sum([1, 1, 8], 3)` is still ok.